# Python doesn't appear in preference window

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am trying to install Pydev in eclipse Helios on windows 7. I have done that through `help/Install new software`. When attempting to configure Eclipse to find my installed Python, (`Window -> Preferences`) the list that appears does not contain Python. When I browse in google about this, someone suggests to run eclipse as administrator. When I try to install the software again, it says that

```
 Software being installed: Pydev Mylyn Integration 0.4.0
 (org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature.feature.group 0.4.0)
  Missing requirement: Pydev Mylyn Integration 0.4.0 
  (org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature.feature.group 0.4.0) requires
 'org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Comment: Try not to install the Pydev Mylyn Integration. Or do you need this?

Comment: @user714965 I dont know exactly the use of it since i am new to python.I just checked all options during installation of plugin

Comment: If you don't want to use Mylyn (or don't know what Mylyn is) you don't need the Pydev Mylyn integration. Else try to install Mylyn from the eclipse update site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using an old version of Eclipse? What I would try first is to [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) the stable Eclipse version (currently Juno), open it with a new workspace location (to avoid any old config files being loaded) and install PyDev using their [suggested method](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) (add the `pydev.org/updates` software source and select their packages).

If you still experience problems after doing this, let us know about it - personally, I never had similar trouble.

Comment: ya i got it.It was the problem with the eclipse helios